# ReactJS - sort by ascending and descending

Tags: reactjs, onchange

Im trying to reorder my results (JSON file) based on the title of my contacts.

The initial render is working fine, showing the results of the JSON file in the order they are in the JSON file.

When i change the select dropdown, i expect it to update the .map function (line 143) that is rendering out the results of the JSON.

What is happening is nothing. no change, no errors, just the select dropdown option changed to the selected value.

Not really sure why its not working, spent a few hours trying to debug, bet its something really simple I'm missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm lost on what the problem is..

```js
var getContactList = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Leanne Graham",
      "username": "Bret",
      "job": "Manager",
      "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
      "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
      "website": "http://www.hildegard.org",
      "company": "Romaguera-Crona"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Ervin Howell",
      "username": "Antonette",
      "job": "CEO",
      "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
      "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
      "website": "http://www.anastasia.net",
      "company": "Deckow-Crist"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Clementine Bauch",
      "username": "Samantha",
      "job": "Manager",
      "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
      "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
      "website": "http://www.ramiro.info",
      "company": "Romaguera-Jacobson"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
      "username": "Karianne",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
      "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
      "website": "http://www.kale.biz",
      "company": "Robel-Corkery"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
      "username": "Kamren",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
      "phone": "(254)954-1289",
      "website": "http://www.demarco.info",
      "company": "Keebler LLC"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
      "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
      "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
      "website": "http://www.ola.org",
      "company": "Considine-Lockman"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
      "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
      "job": "Manager",
      "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
      "phone": "210.067.6132",
      "website": "http://www.elvis.io",
      "company": "Johns Group"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
      "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
      "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
      "website": "http://www.jacynthe.com",
      "company": "Abernathy Group"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Glenna Reichert",
      "username": "Delphine",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
      "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
      "website": "http://www.conrad.com",
      "company": "Yost and Sons"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
      "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
      "job": "Store Clerk",
      "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
      "phone": "024-648-3804",
      "website": "http://www.ambrose.net",
      "company": "Hoeger LLC"
    }
  ];

const App = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      orderSelect: ''
    };
  },
  change: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      orderSelect: e.target.value
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var contactsData = this.props.items,
      orderSelect = this.state.orderSelect.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (String(orderSelect) == "asc") {
      contactsData.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase();
      })
    } else if (String(orderSelect) == "desc") {
      contactsData.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name.toLowerCase() < b.name.toLowerCase();
      })
    } else if (String(orderSelect) == "submitted") {
      contactsData = getContactsList
    }

    return( 
    <div>

      <select onChange={this.change} value={this.state.orderSelect}>
        <option value="" disabled=""> Sort by </option> 
        <option value="submitted"> Submitted Date </option> 
        <option value="asc"> A - Z </option> 
        <option value="desc"> Z - A </option> 
      </select>

      {
        contactsData.map(function(l, index) {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {l.name}
            </div>
          )
        })
      }

      </div>           
    );

  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
<App items={getContactList} />,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Running that snippet is giving me an error

Comment: First thing I'd recommend is to upgrade your React version / Javascript to a minimum of ES6, so you can write with class syntax rather than `createClass`. Next is you should update the question to be more explicit. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? What behavior are you seeing and what behavior are you expecting? Are there any Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I have updated my original question a little bit @Andy Ray

Comment: probably because you are trying to sort / mutate a `prop`. You should make a copy of the data to render `contactsData = [...this.props.items]`

Comment: John Ruddell, I thought i already had, I already have this ''var contactsData = this.props.items', isn't that the same?'

Comment: no. that is an array, so you are pointing to the same location in memory. you need to make a copy of your props array.

Comment: [**Heres a working example doing what you want :)**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-tfp2v) Although I would refactor the sorting to be somewhere other than the render. Probably adjust the array as a state property so you can change the order

Comment: Sweet, cheers, I'll have a look over it, I've noticed you have upgraded the react version, so I'll have a run over that and try and take it all in. Thanks for your help, this gives me a great starting place.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get your answer on this? This is my solution, I hope it helps.

```
getContactList
   .sort(
      ({ job: prevOr }, { job: curOr }) => prevOr - curOr
   )
   .map((slider) => (
      <SliderItem key={slider.order} slider={slider} />
   ))
```

I would create then a ternary, if the value is A - Z the this one, if is Z - A then this code but with curOr - prevOr.